# Why "showPass" function is returning null?

Tags: javascript, function, null

I am trying to write a function but having some errors.
My "showPass" function is returning null

```
<input id="userid" type="password" value="12345">
<button id="showPassButton" onclick="showPass(userid, showPassButton)">Show</button>
    
<script>
       function showPass(passId, btnId) {  
            const pass = document.getElementById('passId');
            console.log(pass);
            const btn = document.getElementById('btnId');
            console.log(btn);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your element with id `passId` and `btnId` ?

Comment: Try first `console.log(passId, btnId)` and see what you get in the console

Comment: Your `showPass` function has no `return` so it returns `undefined`, not `null`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `onclick="showPass('userid', 'showPassButton')">` instead of `onclick="showPass(userid, showPassButton)">` because `getElementById` requires a string. Please take following snippet for reference.

```js
function showPass(passId, btnId) {  
    const pass = document.getElementById(passId);
    console.log(pass);
    const btn = document.getElementById(btnId);
    console.log(btn);
}
```

```html
<input id="userid" type="password" value="12345">
<button id="showPassButton" onclick="showPass('userid', 'showPassButton')">Show</button>
```